# Will Lenovo OneKey Recovery delete my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, lenovo-laptop

I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. Windows won't boot (this happens often) and I want to recover it using the Lenovo OneKey Recovery. I have historically just used it, but now I have Ubuntu on it and I really don't want to go through installing all of the things I use on it again.

Will OneKey recovery reset the entire disk, or just the Windows partition?

Comment: the real question is why you need to constantly recover windows.

Comment: That's a question. I sent it in plenty of times when it was under warranty and they said they fixed it permanently. Unfortunately it's no longer under warranty. Any idea?

Comment: Well, that would be a different question and you have offered zero information.  By all means ask another question and provide as much information as possible and maybe someone can answer.

Answer (score 1):

> In the event you need to use the OneKey recovery system, the personal data stored on the D drive will not be erased as the files on the C drive are restored.

According to [this forum post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Disk-Partitioning-and-OneKey-Recovery-Feature/td-p/8036) Lenovo OneKey Recovery will only restore the C: partition, so your Ubuntu installation should not be compromised.

Comment: To my horror, this is not the case.

Comment: I take it from your reply here that you did not have a backup. Oh well.